# Get related Notion tables data

Tags: python, notion-api

I faced one problem.
My tables have columns where one table is related to another, and when I try to get data from those columns, no related block information is provided.
What method can be used to get such data?

```
  block = client.get_block(notion_table_link)   
  rows = [row for row in block.collection.get_rows()]
  res = getattr(row, some_attribute_from_my_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that the related tables/pages have been granted access to the integration. If not, they will not return any data. Use the relation IDs to pull page information either using the GET page endpoint or the GET Block Children endpoint. The page ID can be used in place of the block ID for GET Block Children.